# narrow down excel list

Tags: excel, drilldown

I have a list of 395 part numbers that I would like to see the details on. My master list contains over 500,000 lines some are duplicate part numbers that contain information for individual locations. What is the best way to see only the 395 numbers?

Answer (score 0):

If your part numbers are in a specific column, copy that column to a new tab.  Then use the RemoveDuplicates feature in the Ribbon Data tab to remove all the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gary mentioned, you can do it Removing Duplicates.
Another solution could be to create a Pivot Table and put your column as a row to get the unique values of the column.